# The pagenumber of subdivision of a complete graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

A [book embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_embedding) of a graph $G$ consists of placing the vertices of $G$ on a spine and assigning edges of the graph to pages so that edges in the same page do not cross each other. The book thickness $bt(G)$ is the minimum number of pages in which the graph $G$ can be embedded.

I wondered whether the following result is right:

Let $ {K_n}$ be a complete graph with $n$ order,  a graph $ {K'_n}$ is from the graph $K_n$ by adding at most one new vertex on each edge $e$ of $K_n$,  then $bt( {K'_n})=bt(K_n).$

I would be very grateful  if someone could give any suggestions.

Comment: I will point out that there already exists a tag called ([tag:extremal-graph-theory]). So if this is what you had in mind, there is no need to create a new tag. (And if there is some distinction between extreme graph theory and extremal graph theory, it would be good to clarify that [in the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/extreme-graph-theory/info).)

Comment: Can you do $K_5$ with each edge subdivided, on 3 pages?  I doubt it.

Comment: I take it back; $K_5$ subdivided can be done.